# button click not firing it's method VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, button

Hello I'm having a problem with my button. When I click it, the button's not firing the method:

```
  Private Sub button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        'Initialize the capture device
        grabber = New Capture()
        grabber.QueryFrame()
        'Initialize the FrameGraber event
        AddHandler Application.Idle, New EventHandler(AddressOf FrameGrabber)
        button1.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

What am I missing in here?

Comment: Go to your form in the designer and double-click the button. Does it go to this method or does it create a new one?

Comment: just delete the button & create again!

Comment: @neknekmouh Joel Coehoorn's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: @neknekmouh - Make sure your button is declared `WithEvents` in the designer (or wherever it's declared): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be something like

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
```

or

```
AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf button1_Click
```

I suppose its vb.net and winforms. With VB6 or WPF is a solution little bit different.

Comment: Hello, I now encounter a new problem, error message says: Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base type.

Comment: @neknekmouh: What is the button1 declaration? (Right click button1 text and Go to definition.

Comment: Sorry I don't know where to find definition :(

Comment: Right click on the 'button1' in button1.Click and select 'Go to definition' from the context menu.

Comment: The declaration should be something as Private WithEvents button1 As button. Is it?

Comment: Nothing, so I put WithEvents there. Thanks to your help! It's now solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Forms designer.
2. Select the Button.
3. In the Properties Pane, bottom right by default, click the "Lightning Bolt" Icon.
4. Find the "Click" entry.
5. Click the small dropdown arrow to the right and select "button1_click".

The handler should now be again associated with your buttons click event.

Comment: If you performed Step #2 above, "Select the Button", then you should have a WithEvents declaration already for the button (its in the hidden designer file for the form).  Did you by chance manually edit this file and remove the "WithEvents" part of the declaration?

Comment: Hey I already solved it! Thanks to ur help. I added WithEvents to my button. God bless

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration like this:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

Comment: Forgot this is VB and all you have to do is add the Handles. Hehe.