# I need to insert a date into a textbox where type = date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, textbox

Okay so i am working on a page in ASP.NET in VB and I have a textbox that lets you pick the date from like a small calendar thing but I need to insert a date in that same textbox when a button is clicked. Here's My Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtActionDate" type="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And when the button is clicked.

```
Protected Sub btnOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOne.Click
txtActionDate.Text = "05261994"
txtActionDate.Text = "05/26/1994"
txtActionDate.Text = "05-26-1994"
End Sub
```

but each one of these does nothing the textbox doesn't show anything different when the button is clicked.

Comment: Are you sure the event is fired? Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445877/button-click-not-firing-its-method-vb-net

Comment: The method is called `btnOne_Click` then the handler is `btnImportTo.Click` are you using the right button? also in the method you are overwriting the data to `txtActionDate` with each line so only the last will show.

Comment: Pleun Yes I know the event fires because I have run the program in debug mode.

Comment: And OneFineDay those are examples I have tried. that's not what it really runs when I Tested it I used one at a time

Comment: HTML5 problem? What browser are you using? Remove the type="date" and check if that works

Comment: Try TextMode="Date" instead of type="date"..

Comment: Pleun I am using chrome and i use the type="date" to allow the user to select a date from a calendar looking thing.
Glk.net I tried changing it to textmode but I got the same results.